# Listview in Scrollview which has multiline text

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-scrollview

There is a textview in listview and the textview's text is too long and it comes in 3 or 4 lines. In that case, the listview is not showing all items.any solutions?

Comment: `Listview in Scrollview` **very bad idea**...

Comment: Have it like, when you click on the TextView, you can show the complete text, by default show one line with dots at end.

Comment: May be you can use `wrap_content` for `textView` to avoid `scroll`...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein-if you have any other idea for not using listviews inside scrollview.Please tell me.

Comment: @AnithaManikandan-my current issue is that I have 3 listviews and in between listviews I have another layouts.have any solution?

Comment: write your xml please

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela-my layout design look like 
<RelativeLayout><LinearLayout>........</LinearLayout><Listview/></RelativeLayout>...........like the 3 more inside scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Textviews maximum length as per your requirement.
For example as bellow :

```
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
    />
```